Are these drywall cracks near windows normal?
For context, 3 story townhouse built in 2016, Seattle area. Here's what the exterior looks like:

I've had the house for 3 years and shortly after purchasing noticed cracks forming in the corners of the house near the windows like so
Second Floor:


Third Floor:

I had a contractor look at it and they said those cracks were just cosmetic and due to the natural sway of the house, as it should be able to sway for earthquakes.
However after a recent storm I've noticed a couple new cracks that look a little more concerning:
Second Floor:

Third Floor:

The new second floor one seems most concerning to me, but I thought I would show them all here for completeness. Does anyone have experience with similar issues and know if this is possibly a more serious issue to be concerned about?

Since some new cracks showed up after a storm, I have reason to suspect there may be water infiltration.  Where?  I have no idea, but I would start at the roof.

I don't think we need to conjecture water damage in the absence of any signs of water.  High winds can cause a building to flex and also occur during storms.  Sure check under the roof for signs of water damage--good to do that occasionally.  I would think that the real question is how to change these locations so as to accept the normal house flex.  Drywall doesn't seem to be cutting it.

A few plasterboard cracks at high stress areas like window corners are nothing to worry about. Looks like just normal motion, not water. Sand spackle, paint. Or ignore until they bother you enough to want to do something about them.

Ok thanks a lot @keshlam

I'd consider using something like acrylic caulk instead of spackle, just because if it flexed before, it'll flex again, and a rigid spackle will just crack again.  Obviously, either way, you may have an issue matching the texture (if you care about that).

Usually the cracks for movement show up on somewhat straight lines where a joint occurs. You may have dissimilar materials coming together that expand and cotract at various levels and directions. Also your foundation may move depending on common regional factors (in Texas we have lots of clay and drought/flooding/seasonal temps make it a wild ride for any structure) You may have regular minor seismic movement that you deal with, but don’t assume all cracks are inevitable. I would hope the builders there have some experience and plan for that but even then you will get cracks. I have never heard of cracks like that being typical of what you see though. We understand the linear cracks along a joint but I don’t know why those would follow a different pattern. I have not seen any solid explanation as to why those would occur. Just my two cents

Thanks @MT Howard. So some of these cracks do not look like normal movement to you?
For "dissimilar materials coming together that expand and cotract at various levels", do  you know the urgency of something like that? Is it generally just cosmetic or can it be more serious?
